# File Format or File Extension is not valid using Spout PHP In Linux CentOS

Tags: php, spout, phpxlsxwriter

I am facing problem in export xlsx format using spout library. I don't know where is the issue in my code. I don't know much about spout library. I have tried many times but the same error occurs again and again when I tried opening the exported excel file in live server (CentOs) . Please guide me where is the issue.

```
#!/usr/bin/php -q
<?PHP
    require_once 'spout-3.1.0/src/Spout/Autoloader/autoload.php';
    
    use Box\Spout\Writer\Common\Creator\WriterEntityFactory;
    use Box\Spout\Writer\Common\Creator\Style\StyleBuilder;
    use Box\Spout\Common\Entity\Style\CellAlignment;
    use Box\Spout\Common\Entity\Style\Color;
    
    $columnHeaders = array("Category",
            "Brand",
            "Model",
            "Sub Category",
            "Description",
            "Price",
            "Online Retailer",
            "Date");
            
    $writer = WriterEntityFactory::createXLSXWriter();
    $writer->openToFile('test.xlsx');

    /** Create a style with the StyleBuilder */
    $style = (new StyleBuilder())
               ->setFontBold()
               ->setFontSize(10)
               ->setFontColor(Color::BLUE)
               ->setShouldWrapText()
               ->setCellAlignment(CellAlignment::LEFT)
               ->setBackgroundColor(Color::YELLOW)
               ->build();

    /** Create a row with cells and apply the style to all cells */
    $row = WriterEntityFactory::createRowFromArray($columnHeaders, $style);

    /** Add the row to the writer */
    $writer->addRow($row);
    $writer->close();
            
            
?>
```

But the same code is perfectly creating the excel file in my xampp local environment (My PC)

Comment: You did not specify what the error is. Hard to help without this.

Answer (score -2):

use `$writer->openToBrowser('test.xlsx');`